# I m getting error in logcat like getNetworkInfo , wifi_p2p_statetracker

Tags: java, android

[Error in Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uGk8.png)
Below is my code for network connection,i m getting "Wifi_P2p_StateTracker" error, how to resolve this error,in AndroidManifest file i have declared all permissions.

```
public class ConnectionDetector {

    private Context context;

    public ConnectionDetector(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {

        boolean wifiDataAvailable = false;
        boolean mobileDataAvailable = false;
        try {
            ConnectivityManager conManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo[] networkInfo = conManager.getAllNetworkInfo();
            for (NetworkInfo netInfo : networkInfo) {

                if (netInfo.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                    if (netInfo.isConnected())
                        wifiDataAvailable = true;

                if (netInfo.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                    if (netInfo.isConnected())
                        mobileDataAvailable = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return wifiDataAvailable || mobileDataAvailable;
    }

}
```

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace

Comment: `I m getting error in logcat` ... Then share your logcat.

Comment: @Hrundi V.Bakshi ,i have attached Logcat,please can u help me out with solution..Thanku

Comment: Can anyone please reply for my question ?